# Adding spring-boot-starter-web to dependencies breaks multiple datasources

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a project with 3 different DataSources. It works fine if the project is run from with spring-boot:run only with these dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
```

Here is one datasource, they are all pretty much the same, just changing bean names and database information

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "emfIntranet", transactionManagerRef = "tmIntranet", basePackages = {"com.vnt.intranet.repositories"})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "databases.sistemas")
public class IntranetPersistence {

    private String address;
    private String schema;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String eclipselinklog;
    private Boolean sqllog;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dsIntranet")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + address + "/" + schema);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(3);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform");
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(sqllog);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "emfIntranet")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.vnt.intranet.entities");
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("intranet");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", eclipselinklog); // SEVERE / FINEST

        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "tmIntranet")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

    public void setSchema(String schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEclipselinklog() {
        return eclipselinklog;
    }

    public void setEclipselinklog(String eclipselinklog) {
        this.eclipselinklog = eclipselinklog;
    }

    public Boolean getSqllog() {
        return sqllog;
    }

    public void setSqllog(Boolean sqllog) {
        this.sqllog = sqllog;
    }
}
```

I can access all datasources with no problem... One of them is annotated with @Primary.

But if I uncomment spring-boot-starter-web dependency it breaks it and gives me:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [emfIntranet, entityManagerFactory, emfMkRadius, emfMkData]
```

I'm trying to convert this to a web project with no success...

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Adding other classes for clarity:

MkDataPersistence.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "emfMkData", transactionManagerRef = "tmMkData", basePackages = {"org.example.mkdata.repositories"})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "databases.mkdata")
public class MkDataPersistence {

    private String address;
    private String schema;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String eclipselinklog;
    private Boolean sqllog;

    @Bean(name = "dsMkData")
    javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + address + "/" + schema);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(3);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter getHibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(sqllog);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "emfMkData")
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getHibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.example.mkdata.entities");
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("mkdata");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", eclipselinklog); // SEVERE / FINEST

        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "tmMkData")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

    public void setSchema(String schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEclipselinklog() {
        return eclipselinklog;
    }

    public void setEclipselinklog(String eclipselinklog) {
        this.eclipselinklog = eclipselinklog;
    }

    public Boolean getSqllog() {
        return sqllog;
    }

    public void setSqllog(Boolean sqllog) {
        this.sqllog = sqllog;
    }
}
```

MkRadiusPersistence.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement()
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "emfMkRadius", transactionManagerRef = "tmMkRadius", basePackages = {"org.example.mkradius.repositories"})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "databases.mkradius")
public class MkRadiusPersistence {

    private String address;
    private String schema;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String eclipselinklog;
    private Boolean sqllog;

    @Bean(name = "dsMkRadius")
    javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://" + address + "/" + schema);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(3);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter getHibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(sqllog);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "emfMkRadius")
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getHibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("org.example.mkradius.entities");
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("mkradius");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", eclipselinklog); // SEVERE / FINEST

        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "tmMkRadius")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

    public void setSchema(String schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEclipselinklog() {
        return eclipselinklog;
    }

    public void setEclipselinklog(String eclipselinklog) {
        this.eclipselinklog = eclipselinklog;
    }

    public Boolean getSqllog() {
        return sqllog;
    }

    public void setSqllog(Boolean sqllog) {
        this.sqllog = sqllog;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Application.class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.example.startup" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Autowired
    CableRouteRepository cableRouteRepository;

    @Autowired
    CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Autowired
    RadAcctRepository radAcctRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                .showBanner(false)
                .sources(Application.class)
                .run(args);

        Application app = context.getBean(Application.class);

//        for (String bean: context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
//            logger.info(bean);
//        }

        app.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        logger.info("Application.start()");

        logger.info("{}", cableRouteRepository.findAll());
        logger.info("{}", cityRepository.findAll());
        logger.info("{}", radAcctRepository.findTest());
    }


}
```

This is the starter class... I printed every repository as a test (each repository here is on a different DataSource)... They work fine as long as I don't have spring-starter-web on the classpath.

**EDIT 3**

Github Repo
https://github.com/mtrojahn/test-multiple-databases

I hope I did it right... I never really worked with Github :)

**EDIT 4**

Github updated properly with the failing code.

As a reminder if the dependency bellow is commented, the code works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And if the dependency above is uncommented but the code bellow is changed in the IntranetPersistence.class from:

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "emfIntranet")
```

to

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
```

It overwrites the default bean and starts to fail with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class org.example.intranet.entities.CableRoute
```

Comment: Where are `emfMkRadius` and `emfMkData` declared? I can see that `emfIntranet` is `@Primary`, is one of the other two as well?

Comment: I will edit with them, but they are pretty much the same, hence why I didn't post them all.

Comment: Spring Boot's `entityManagerFactory` bean is `@Primary` but it should have been switched off by any one of your `EntityManagerFactory` beans as its creation is conditional on their being no `EntityManagerFactory` bean in the context. What does your main class look like? Are you referencing any of Boot's auto-configuration classes directly?

Comment: Main class looks good to me. Can you share a repo somewhere with all the code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the interest! :) I added a repo with the test-case.

Comment: The code you've shared doesn't reproduce the problem. It fails with `Not an managed type: class org.example.intranet.entities.CableRoute`. I did notice info log messages about beans being overridden. I doubt that's the cause of the problem, but it almost certainly isn't what you want to be happening.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry... I just noticed the code I shared is altered with a little test I was doing. I attempted to overwrite entityManagerFactory on the IntranetPersistence class since you commented it's also primary. I renamed a bean there... That apparently made the error go away and it now fails with a not managed class (that also is an annoying problem everytime I try to go with no xml). I'll try to update the code with the proper error soon.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the code was in my work computer and it has been turned off during the weekend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being affected by the behaviour of Spring Boot 1.2's JPA auto-configuration. It only switches off the creation of its own `entityManagerFactory` bean if there's a user-defined `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. You're using `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` but calling `afterPropertiesSet` and `getObject` on it yourself rather than allowing the container to do so for you. This leaves the context will multiple `@Primary` `EntityManagerFactory` beans. This has been [improved in Spring Boot 1.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2803) so that a user-declared `EntityManagerFactory` bean will also switch off the auto-configuration.

This causes a problem when trying to create `openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` as it needs an `EntityManagerFactory` and the context has no way of knowing whic of the two `@Primary` beans it should choose.

There are a few ways to proceed. You could update your configuration to define beans that are of type `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`s rather than `EntityManagerFactory`. Another is to disable the creation of the interceptor by adding the following to your `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open_in_view: false
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to fix it. Thanks for your time and interest :)

Comment: @Coderdood I've updated my answer with some more details of what's happening and why.

Comment: Yep, I changed my bean to LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and it did the trick. Works even with spring.jpa.open_in_view = true now. Thanks!